# Why is indexing keep being turned off in my computer and how do I turned it back on, permanently if possible?

Tags: search-indexing

[image]

This is what I see when I try to find stuffs.

Clicking turning on indexing show me this

[image]

Nothing on that pictures tell me if indexing is on or not.

How do I know?

Searching anything in start menu bar will have something that show that indexing is off. But is it really off?

How do I know?

If I go to msc and look at windows search

I got this

[image]

Basically it says windows search is running but I cannot restart stop or anything.

Comment: You're not supposed to be able to stop and start WSearch from that dialog. I can confirm my system, which does have indexing working, cannot stop WSearch due to the fact it has multiple dependencies. Try just rebuilding the search index.

Answer (score 1):

Your second image shows on top the message "Indexing complete",
which means that indexing is indeed running.

To verify which folders are being indexed:

- Run *Start > Indexing Options*.
- In the Indexing Options window, click the Modify button.
  This will open a new window with the list of locations that
  are indexed.
- Make sure that the locations you want to be indexed are checked.
- Click OK to save your changes.
- Windows 10 will then begin indexing these locations in the
  background, which might take some time.

Comment: Yes the pictures are NOT consistent. In the first picture, indexing is clearly turned off. In the second and third it looks like it's on.

It's the same computer. No change whatsoever.